# Sox/Terminal is teling me 'Could not rewind in audio file'

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sox

I'm running this command on terminal:

```
for i in  $(ls -1 /home/pi/Desktop/Music/Acapella/*.mp3|sort -R); do sox -t mp3 $i -t wav - ; done | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 102.1  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt "ZSFM"
```

Basically, it uses a forloop to go through all the files in a dir and convert them into wav files  on-the-fly, and then pipe it into the pifm command.
The only problem is, though, after the first file it says:

```
sox WARN sox: `-' output clipped 773 samples; decrease volume?
Could not rewind in audio file, terminating
Terminating: cleanly deactivated the DMA engine and killed the carrier
```

I'm not sure if its a sox problem or a terminal problem. what does it mean (and how do I fix it)?

I did put 'done' after the pifm command, but then it runs the pifm command once for every file, but I want the pifm command to be constantly running, and the forloop will only go on the file its playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving sox one file. It converts and stream, then ends before getting next file.

You could do it in various of ways. And, no, do not use `ls` like that

I'm using `play` for test purpose:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

path="/home/pi/Desktop/Music/Acapella/"

find "$path" -name '*.mp3' -print0 |
    sort -z -R |
    xargs -0 cat |
    sox -t mp3 - -t wav - |
    play -
```

Here one say

- `find` files in `$path` where `-name` ends with `.mp3` and print file-names separated with `\0` zero byte.
- `sort` random `-R` input from pipe / `find` which is `-z` zero separated. (Aka shuffle)
- `xargs` concatenate files given by `-0` zero delimited filenames.
- `sox`

  - `-t mp3 -`: Type mp3 read from stdin (standard in)
  - `-t wav -`: Type wav write to stdout (standard out)
- `play` data from stdin `-`

---

If you can guarantee no new-lines in filenames you could also use a temporary playlist. [Here M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), se wiki if you want to go fancy.

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

# ARG 1 is path
path="$1"

# Create temporary file to use as playlist
playlist="$(mktemp /tmp/sox.XXXXXXXX.m3u)"
# Delete playlist on exit
trap 'rm "$playlist"' EXIT

#Create playlist
find "$path" -name '*.mp3' -print |
    sort -R >"$playlist"

sox "$playlist" -t wav - | play -
```

Comment: How can I have it shufle the files in the dir without using the ls thing?

Comment: @horace The files are shuffled using `sort -R`. In both examples.